# How can solve the error in flutter_paystack?

Tags: flutter

1. Type mismatch: inferred type is Activity? but Activity was expected
2. Type mismatch: inferred type is BinaryMessenger? but BinaryMessenger was expected

Answer (score 0):

I think this might be that the library is not yet optimized to support Flutter 3 which came out recently. Try to communicate with the devs on their github this error and they might be able to fix it

Answer (score 0):

add this to your pubspec.yaml file, this will solve it for now.

```
 flutter_paystack:
   git:
     url: https://github.com/definitelyme/flutter_paystack.git
     ref: a4a33c3dd0a12f46d655a2e63d11e9f20ba82d01
```